# How to remove unknown requests from the webpage

Tags: path, path-finding

When trying to test webpage speed using the tool 
http://tools.pingdom.com
I found that there are unknown requests among the requests list
I did search for the path of the request in the filemanager and I contacted many developers to find it and remove it but we failed to find it

[website speed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wilp.jpg)

How to find that requests or sources 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I personally trust [Google pagespeed tools](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to test my website speed. I find that it is far more reliable and very easy to understand. It even has links to methods that you can use to speed up your site **whilst creating a minimal number of extra requests**...

Comment: I do not have issue with the tool I have issue with the requests which appears such as ads networks cookie (see the screenshot in the question)